# Wordpress + Algolia query parameters conflict

Tags: php, wordpress, algolia

On my Wordpress site I use Algolia to search Woocommerce products.

Everything works as expected on category pages e.g. `www.example.com/products`

The problem occurs on the domain root. When I do the search, query parameters are being added: `www.example.com/?q=myquery&hPP=12&idx=all&p=0&is_v=1`, and now if I reload the page, I'll be taken to the page of blog posts, most probably Wordpress native search results...

Desired action would be the same as it is on the category pages, or anywhere other than root, so that after page reload it should show the exact same page with exact same search query.

Possible solutions I can think of:

1. Disable query parameters for Wordpress, so that it would not take any action if the URL contains one
2. Change Algolia's query parameters into something that Wordpress would not take as a search query, the problem seems to be the `&p=0`, removing this, and reloading the page works as desired.

PS! In the Wordpress permalinks settings I have chosen `http://www.domain.com/%postname%/`

Comment: So, thanks to @Jerska the problem is solved easily by adding the `search.urlSync.mapping = {p:'px'}`. Although, it would still be interesting to know if there's a solution for this on Wordpress side as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're aware of this, but since others could stumble upon your question, I'll just state here that the Algolia for WordPress integration is, at the time of the writing, currently in *beta and not supported* (see the warning in [the repo's README](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-wordpress#warning)).

Also, based on the parameters you're talking about, it seems like you're using the latest version in the develop branch of the repository.

In this version, the query parameters are added in the URL by a library used internally called [`instantsearch.js`](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/).

---

This library, on initialization, exposes the [`urlSync.useHash`](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/documentation/#initialization) parameter which will make the library store these parameters in the hash instead of the query parameters. Just set it to `true`.

> If set to true, the url will be hash based. Otherwise, it’ll use the query parameters using the modern history API.

---

Since here there seems to be only one parameter which causes trouble, the [`urlSync.mapping`](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/documentation/#initialization) parameter might be a better solution. However, I'm not sure this option is available in the `instantsearch.js` version the integration is using.

> Object used to define replacement query parameter to use in place of another. Keys are current query parameters and value the new value, e.g. `{ q: 'query' }`.

In your case, this would be `{ p: 'new_parameter_name_that_wont_conflict' }`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The second option seems to be exactly what I was looking for, even the first one would do. But when I add either of them to my `search = instantsearch({})` object right after `urlSync: true`, I will get the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`. Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Okay, figured it out now: `search.urlSync.mapping = {p:'px'}` did the job, most importantly fixed the main problem! Thanks!

Comment: I actually thinking about `search = instantsearch({urlSync: {mapping: { p: 'px' }}})`.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, although my version works as well!

Comment: For folks ending up reading this, note that the plugin is from now on available on the official plugin directory here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-by-algolia-instant-relevant-results/